# Is there a way to create multiple product pages in Opencart?

Tags: opencart

My client's t-shirt website has 2 types of products. One is just normal t-shirts. The other one is dynamic t-shirt design creation. The normal t-shirts can use the default product templates but dynamic products need a different type of functionality in it. Will creating different templates make it possible to resolve this issue or do I need to do more than that?

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate category or add a new field for selecting product type for dynamic t-shirts.

Depending on either of the options mentioned above use 2 product templates or add condition based html code in the existing product template.

Have a nice day :) !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using tabs (depending on your theme) then loading the custom template via an additional method and ajax.

Look at how the checkout controllers and templates/javascript work in the checkout process and model that for your custom tshirt builder.